# Wait on a mutex without acquiring it

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

I have been writing a small microservice so familiarize myself with Go and it's concurrency mechanisms.

In my program I have a struct that has a state and I want to sync that state so that multiple goroutines will be able to read it, but not while another goroutine is updateing that state.

Initially I thought RWMutax was what I need, but going by the documentation, only one goroutine may aquire read lock at any given moument. I'm going by this line:

> "If a goroutine holds a RWMutex for reading and another goroutine
> might call Lock, no goroutine should expect to be able to acquire a
> read lock until the initial read lock is released."

Is there any way to wait on a mutex without acquiring a lock?

something along the lines of:

```golang
type stateful struct {
    state        int
    stateMutex   sync.Mutex
    beingUpdated bool
}

type Stateful interface {
    GetState() int
    SetState(st int)
}

func createStateful (sa string) stateful {
    return server{state: 0, stateMutex: sync.Mutex{}, beingUpdated: false}
}

func (s *stateful) SetState(st int) {
    s.stateMutex.Lock()
    s.beingUpdated = true
    s.state = st
    s.beingUpdated = false
    s.stateMutex.Unlock()
}

func (s *stateful) GetState() bool {
    if s.beingUpdated {
        // wait for s.stateMutex to be unlocked
    }

    return s.state
}
```

Comment: "only one goroutine may aquire read lock at any given moument" why do you think that a RWMutex works this way? If that were true the whole idea of the RW mutex would be voided.

Comment: from the documantaion: "If a goroutine holds a RWMutex for reading and another goroutine might call Lock, no goroutine should expect to be able to acquire a read lock until the initial read lock is released." I took this line to meen this

Comment: It reads "another goroutine might call **Lock**" not **Rlock**. Of course only a single Lock for writing can be given without any other reader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have misread the [sync.RWMutex docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex):

> ... The lock can be held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single
> writer.

So your code simplifies like so:

```
type stateful struct {
    l     sync.RWMutex // style: place lock above ...
    state int        //        ... the field it protects
}

func (s *stateful) SetState(st int) {
    s.l.Lock()
    defer s.l.Unlock()

    s.state = st
}

func (s *stateful) GetState() int {
    s.l.RLock()
    defer s.l.RUnlock()

    return s.state
}
```